# cakephp: parse error in $this->model->field(

Tags: cakephp, parse-error

i'm getting the following syntax error:
Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\merry_flowers\controllers\merry_parents_controller.php on line 12. What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

when i try to run the following code:

```
<?php

var $merryparent_id=$this->MerryParent->field('id',
                                        array('MerryParent.name'=>$this.data['MerryParent']['name'],
                                        'MerryParent.email'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['email'])
                                        );
               ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use:

```
array('MerryParent.name'=>$this.data['MerryParent']['name']
```

instead of:

```
array('MerryParent.name'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['name']
```

You're using a . instead of a -> to dereference $this.

Change to "->", and it should work.

Comment: Hi, yes, it worked fine after changing $this.data to $this->data. I would like to know if the following will also give the same result? $merryparent_id=$this->MerryParent->find('first',array(
         'conditions'=>array(
           'MerryParent.name'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['name'],
           'MerryParent.email'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['email']
           ),
         'fields'=>array('MerryParent.id')
          );